# How to Substring column in R with different length to substring in each row and convert it to numeric type?

Tags: r, string

I want to create an additional column in a dataframe, which is a substring from an existing column in the dataframe, but using same start points and different end points.

specifically, the columns are in string format and the the characters just before the first space needs to be extracted into a new column and then converted into numeric type

Example of what I currently have:

```
HH_ID <- c("A123", "B123", "C123")
HH_MEMBERS <- c("12 Members","8 Members","14 Members")

df <- data.frame(HH_ID, HH_MEMBERS)

print(df)

        HH_ID       HH_MEMBERS
1       A123        12 Members
2       B123         8 Members
3       C123        14 Members
```

This is an example of what I would like, New_members column is created which contains the initial numeric part of entries from HH_Memebrs column and this string numeric data is converted finally to integer

```
        HH_ID       HH_MEMBERS   NEW_MEMBERS
1       A123        12 Members     12
2       B123         8 Members      8
3       C123        14 Members     14
```

Any help would be appreciated

I have tried -> substring(col_name, 1,1) but this is not capturing the string which has multiple digits

Comment: `transform(df,NEW_MEMBERS = as.integer(sub("\\D+", "", HH_MEMBERS)))`

Answer (score -1):

```
df %>%
  mutate(NEW_MEMBERS = as.numeric(sub("(\\d+).+", "\\1", HH_MEMBERS)))

  HH_ID HH_MEMBERS NEW_MEMBERS
1  A123 12 Members          12
2  B123  8 Members           8
3  C123 14 Members          14
```